# Start and stop server when I want

Tags: android, kotlin, ktor

Hi I'm making an android app that runs a ktor server on the background. The server should be opened and closed depending on the situations.
I've created a singleton with an embeddedServer using Jetty. Then I call

```
embeddedServerKt.start(wait = false)
```

The problem is that when I close and reopen the server this happens

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.service.rcarniproducts.debug, PID: 15768
    java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: event executor terminated
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.reject(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:926)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.offerTask(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:353)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.addTask(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:346)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.execute(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:828)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.execute(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:818)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.register(AbstractChannel.java:483)
        at io.netty.channel.SingleThreadEventLoop.register(SingleThreadEventLoop.java:87)
        at io.netty.channel.SingleThreadEventLoop.register(SingleThreadEventLoop.java:81)
        at io.netty.channel.MultithreadEventLoopGroup.register(MultithreadEventLoopGroup.java:86)
        at io.ktor.server.netty.EventLoopGroupProxy.register(Unknown Source:2)
        at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap.initAndRegister(AbstractBootstrap.java:323)
        at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap.doBind(AbstractBootstrap.java:272)
        at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap.bind(AbstractBootstrap.java:268)
        at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap.bind(AbstractBootstrap.java:253)
        at io.ktor.server.netty.NettyApplicationEngine.start(NettyApplicationEngine.kt:177)
        at com.service.rcarniproducts.WebServer.start(WebServer.kt:57)
        at com.service.rcarniproducts.ui.EditProductsBottomSheet.onViewCreated(EditProductsBottomSheet.kt:49)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:332)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1187)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1356)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1434)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1497)
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:447)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2169)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1992)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1947)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1849)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$4.run(FragmentManager.java:413)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:233)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8010)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:631)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:978)
```

Is there any way to open and close the server without this error?

Comment: I would assume you can't really start the same server again. After shutting down it is in a permanently stopped state. You can very easily create a new server with `embeddedServer()`.

Comment: I've created an issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTOR-2762 to address this problem. As a workaround you can recreate a server to start it again as @broot suggested.